# how to parse a generated csv string in python

Tags: python, string, csv

So I have this complex string that has been generated in python whilst parsing a csv file. here is the state of the string right now:

```
[
    {'id': 1463, 'name': 'culture clash'},
    {'id': 2964, 'name': 'future'},
    {'id': 3386, 'name': 'space war'},
    {'id': 3388, 'name': 'space colony'},
    {'id': 3679, 'name': 'society'},
    {'id': 3801, 'name': 'space travel'},
    {'id': 9685, 'name': 'futuristic'},
    {'id': 9840, 'name': 'romance'},
    {'id': 9882, 'name': 'space'},
    {'id': 9951, 'name': 'alien'},
    {'id': 10148, 'name': 'tribe'},
    {'id': 10158, 'name': 'alien planet'},
    {'id': 10987, 'name': 'cgi'},
    {'id': 11399, 'name': 'marine'},
    {'id': 13065, 'name': 'soldier'},
    {'id': 14643, 'name': 'battle'},
    {'id': 14720, 'name': 'love affair'},
    {'id': 165431, 'name': 'anti war'},
    {'id': 193554, 'name': 'power relations'},
    {'id': 206690, 'name': 'mind and soul'},
    {'id': 209714, 'name': '3d'},
    ]
```

So say that this string is stored in a variable called x. Is there a faster way to parse this string other than using .split('something') over and over again whilst molding the string back together until there are no outliers left?

What I am trying to achieve is to have something that appears much more readable and easy to manipulate like:

```
id: someNumber, name: someName... repeat until no more data
```

What I have attempted was to split the string then mold it back together multiple times until desired result had been achieved. Or is there a much better way to parse as well as manipulate this string?

Basically I need to extract all of the id's and the corresponding names to later insert into a table.

Comment: You can parse that string using the *loads()* function from the *json* module the result of which will be a list of dictionaries

Comment: im trying to limit the number of libraries used is there a better way?

Comment: It looks like your data _is_ already parsed into a JSON representation. Without knowledge of the code which created this, it's really unclear how you ended up with this. Python by itself can easily parse CSV but you seem to have ended up doing something else; what exactly is hard to guess from your exposition.

Comment: @itsMe Please feel free to write your own JSON parser

Comment: Not wanting to use the standard library is ... weird. One of the reasons Python is useful and popular is that it comes with a very good standard library which provide CSV and JSON parsers (and much, much more) without bloating the language itself. If you don't want to `import` anything, ever, you might as well start writing C (and even then you will need to `#include` stuff).

Comment: @itsMe You ask if there's "a better way". No there isn't. For the data as presented, the **best** way is to use the *json* module

Comment: @itsMe I see your point about not using "libraries". But you have to know that `json` is part of Python. It is not an extern 3rd party library from another source. It is installed with your Python interpreter and not just loaded by default. There is really no good reason to not load `json`. Maybe just your teacher told you that you are not allowed to use libraries in your homework?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you really don't want to import any common modules you could do this but note that the implementation is very specific to the data as shown the question:

```
yourstring = """[{"id": 1463, "name": "culture clash"}, {"id": 2964, "name": "future"}, {"id": 3386, "name": "space war"}, {"id": 3388, "name": "space colony"}, {"id": 3679, "name": "society"}, {"id": 3801, "name": "space travel"}, {"id": 9685, "name": "futuristic"}, {"id": 9840, "name": "romance"}, {"id": 9882, "name": "space"}, {"id": 9951, "name": "alien"}, {"id": 10148, "name": "tribe"}, {"id": 10158, "name": "alien planet"}, {"id": 10987, "name": "cgi"}, {"id": 11399, "name": "marine"}, {"id": 13065, "name": "soldier"}, {"id": 14643, "name": "battle"}, {"id": 14720, "name": "love affair"}, {"id": 165431, "name": "anti war"}, {"id": 193554, "name": "power relations"}, {"id": 206690, "name": "mind and soul"}, {"id": 209714, "name": "3d"}]"""

for d in eval(yourstring):
    print(f'id: {d["id"]}, name: {d["name"]}')
```

**Output:**

```
id: 1463, name: culture clash
id: 2964, name: future
id: 3386, name: space war
id: 3388, name: space colony
id: 3679, name: society
id: 3801, name: space travel
id: 9685, name: futuristic
id: 9840, name: romance
id: 9882, name: space
id: 9951, name: alien
id: 10148, name: tribe
id: 10158, name: alien planet
id: 10987, name: cgi
id: 11399, name: marine
id: 13065, name: soldier
id: 14643, name: battle
id: 14720, name: love affair
id: 165431, name: anti war
id: 193554, name: power relations
id: 206690, name: mind and soul
id: 209714, name: 3d
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm hoping that you have imported and used csv module. Then appended the dictionary in a list. So, it is "list" and not a "string".

You can use the following to print this list:

```
for i in range(len(test)):
    print(f'id : {test[i]["id"]} name : {test[i]["name"]},', end=" ")
```

Here `test` is the name of the list. The output is:

```
id : 1463, name : culture clash id : 2964, name : future id : 3386, ....
```

Comment: @ArthurKing I'm not asking to import anything. The ask is to print the list of dictionaries in readable format. That's what I've done in above for loop.

Comment: You specifically stated that you "hope" OP has imported the *csv* module. How else does *test* get constructed?

Answer (score 0):

## Solution

Because the content of your string is valid Python code you can just treat it as this.

```
yourstring = eval(yourstring)
print(type(yourstring))  # <class 'list'>
print(len(yourstring))  # 21
print(type(yourstring[0]))  # <class 'dict'>
```

This makes `yourstring` a `list()` object with a `dict()` in each element.

## Warning

But it is absolutely not recommended to use `eval()` because of security reasons. But your "minimal" working example does not offer more informations' to find a better solution. As others said the `csv` and `json` module of Python are a good start for a better and more secure solution.

Comment: I have seen so many times so-called Python "experts" stating that *eval()* is evil and is to be avoided. I assume you don't agree with that standpoint